# Jpype java to python type conversions

Tags: python, jpype

Say I create a simple java type with jpype:

```
jt = jpype.java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()
print(jt)
print(type(jt))

pt = int(jt)
print(pt)
print(type(pt))
```

This produces:

```
1693604984710
<java class 'JLong'>
1693604984710
<class 'int'>
```

as expected.

Now my problem here is that I have a class with a bunch of getters that I want to call and put results into a python dict. That part works fine, however I don't get `int`s, I get `JLong`s (and similar for other java classes) which causes issues downstream.

Is there something in jpype that allows standard java types (including boxed types such as `Integer`) to be converted to python types or do I have to do it manually?